# Netlink access inside a network namespace

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, socket, namespace, network-namespaces

I'm trying set up an IPsec gateway (strongSwan) on a Raspberry Pi 2.

The Pi was already providing a number of services on the LAN using a private IP address.

My initial attempt to turn it into an IPsec gateway involved just adding a public IP address to the same interface (`eth0`) and enable strongSwan SA on this new address. This works, and after enabling the `pcrypt` module I managed to get ~80Mbps decryption throughput, which really is pretty good all things considered.

I then decided to try and isolate the strongSwan stuff into a separate network namespace. I did `ip netns add vpn`, created a `macvlan` device on `eth0`, then add it to the `vpn` namespace. I then run `ip netns exec vpn ipsec start` and everything just works again.

However, `pcrypt` doesn't seem to be active anymore inside the namespace, and the throughput drops down to about ~25Mbps. I usually enable `pcrypt` using `crconf`, as per [this instruction](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Pcrypt). When invoked inside the namespace, it keeps failing with a netlink error. Running `strace crconf` gives this gem:

```
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_CRYPTO) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [32768], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [1048576], 4) = 0
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, 12) = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=997, groups=00000000}, [12]) = 0
send(3, "\24\0\0\0\23\0\1\3U\212\327V\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 20, 0) = -1 ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

So the kernel is refusing a connection to the `NETLINK_CRYPTO` socket from inside the network namespace.

**QUESTION: How do I allow a connection to `NETLINK_CRYPTO` from my network namespace?**